# Socket.io tutorial creates extra messages

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm following the [Socket.IO tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), but I am running into an issue where the number of messages that display on the page increase exponentially, making the chat client ineffective.

Some cursory searching is telling me that it involves event handlers, but I haven't found anything definitive on how to use them in this context. **What and where do I need to use these event handlers, and why?**

My index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // console.log('a user connected');
  // socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  //   console.log('user disconnected');
  // });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    //console.log('message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script>

   function doDid(){
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
   };
  </script>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button onclick="doDid()">Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you subscribe to the "chat message" event each time you press your button.

You should only run this code once:

```
 var socket = io();

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
```

So you should change your code like this:

```
<script>
  var socket = io();

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });

   function doDid(){
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
     });  
   };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var socket = io();
```

This line creates a connection to socket.io. Each time you call it you are creating another connection. Try only calling that once instead of on each send.

To clarify, the `io()` function is a *factory* not an *accessor*.

**Edit**:

Looks like the socket.io client actually does cache sockets it creates and doesn't create multiple connections.

However, I also noticed you are binding events in that function, but are calling it each click, so you are rebinding each time. Call your function only once at startup.

Comment: Helpful to know, but the issue with multiple messages still occurs.

Comment: @Thassa you need to move `var socket = io()` _and_ `socket.on()` outside of `doDid()` entirely.

Comment: Actually, just move your event handling. You are already binding to the submit event, don't call that function on submit as well. Call it on page load.